# Linear transformation and it's properties

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a $p− 1$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^p$ . Given a vector $t$ in $\Bbb R^p/M$,
show that we can find a linear transformation $B : \Bbb R^p → \Bbb R$ such that the
null space of $B$ is $M$ and $Bt = 1$.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @paf I tried using rank-nullity theorem, but couldn't solve it

Comment: What are $A$ and $\Bbb R^p/A$?

Comment: @paf i've edited the question

Comment: @mathkid I guess you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus M$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^p/M$.

Comment: Why haven't you answered (yes) to @heptagon : $\mathbb{R}^p/M$ is a 1D quotient space... nothing to do with $\mathbb{R}^p\setminus M$ ($\mathbb{R}^p$ without $M$) which is the correct way to write things. Mathematics is also a question of accurate writing...

Comment: @JeanMarie, I agree. mathkid, I also think that the current formulation makes no sense, so I'm voting this question down.

Comment: Yes, but why did you downvote my answer?

Comment: @paf Well, if the question makes no sense, then so does the answer.

Comment: So you didn't read carefully my answer which begins by "repairing the non-sense" (replacing t by t')

Comment: @paf I don't see this in your answer, more than that everything there tells me you try answering it as stated. In particular, already the first line does not seem to be OK - the statement is neither false nor true, it is just a piece of nonsense.

Comment: "you try answering it as stated": **no**, I replaced t by t'!

Comment: "the statement is neither false nor true, it is just a piece of nonsense": in maths, every statement is either true or false. Since it's not true, thus it's false! I'll stop here the discussion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the statement is false if $t=0$ in $\Bbb R^p/M$ because in this case, $t$ is the class of an element $t'$ of $M$ and $M=\text{Ker}\,B \Rightarrow Bt'=0\neq 1$.

Now, if $t\neq 0$, then $t'\notin M$ and the line $L:=\langle t'\rangle$ satisfies $M\oplus L=\Bbb R^p$. Thus if $\pi$ is the projection on $L$ along $M$ (i.e., if $x=x_M+x_L$, then $\pi(x)=x_L$) and if $\varphi : L\to \Bbb R$ is defined by $\varphi(\lambda t')=\lambda,\;\forall\lambda\in\Bbb R$, we see that $B=\varphi\circ\pi$ satisfies $\text{Ker}\,B=M$ and $Bt=1$.

**Edit:** 
1. $B$ is linear: indeed, if $x=x_M+\lambda t'\in\Bbb R^p$, $y=y_M+\mu t'\in\Bbb R^p$ and $a\in\Bbb R$ then $ax+y=(ax_M+y_M)+(a\lambda+\mu)t'$ so
$$B(ax+y)=\varphi(\pi(ax+y))= \varphi((a\lambda+\mu)t') = a\lambda+\mu$$
and
$$aB(x)+B(y)=a\varphi(\pi(x))+\varphi(\pi(y))=a\varphi(\lambda t')+\varphi(\mu t')=a\lambda+\mu$$

2. By definition of $\pi$, $M\subseteq \text{Ker}\,\pi$ thus $M\subseteq \text{Ker}\,B$. Now, if $\text{Ker}\,B\neq M$ then $\text{Ker}\,B$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^p$ containing strictly a $(p-1)$-subspace, hence $\text{Ker}\,B$ would be all $\Bbb R^p$. This is false because $Bt'=1$. Thus $\text{Ker}\,B=M$.

Comment: could you please elaborate  how B is linear transformation and how Ker B = M?

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: Why is there a downvote? Could the downvoter explain?